# This program should give the AND of the following numbers. What does this mean?

Tags: c++, numbers

For an assignment in my C++ programming class, I was given the following code.  The assignment simply says "This program should give the AND of the following numbers"  Was wondering if could get clarification on the meaning.  I have an idea but I think I still need a bit of advice.  The code was provided jumbled on purpose which I had to clear up.  Here is is cleaned up:

```
// Question2
// This program should give the AND of the inputted numbers.

#include <iostream>

//**Needs namespace statement to directly access cin and cout without using std::
using namespace std;
//**Divided up statements that are running together for better readability
//**Used more spacing in between characters and lines to further increase readability

////void main()
//**Main function should include int as datatype; main is not typically defined as a void function
int main()
{
int i;
int k;

//**Changed spacing to properly enclose entire string
cout << "Enter 0 (false) or 1 (true) for the first value: " << endl;
cin >> i;

cout<< "Enter 0 (false) or 1 (true) for the second value: " << endl;
cin >> k;

//**Spaced out characters and separated couts by lines
//**to help with readability
cout << "AND" << endl;
cout << "k\t| 0\t| 1" << endl;
cout << "---\t| ---\t| ---" << endl;
cout << "0\t| 0\t| 0" << endl;
cout << "1\t| 0\t| 1" << endl;
    if(i==1&k==1)
        cout <<"Result is TRUE" << endl;
    else cout << "Result is FALSE" <<endl;
//**Main function typically includes return statement of 0 to end program execution
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The fact that `using namespace std;` is included in exercises for a class makes me cringe.

Answer (score 3):

Every number has a binary representation. They're asking for the logical and of the bits. Look up the `&` operator.

Answer (score 1):

'&' is a bitwise and, which means it takes the binary representation of two numbers and compares each bit in the first number against the bit in the same position on the second.  If both are 1, the resultant bit in the same position in the output number is 1, otherwise the bit is zero.  `if (i&k)` would have the same result (assuming the input was always 0 or 1), but anyway your if statement compares whether the first bit is 0 or 1, and if both are 1 returns one.

Answer (score 0):

```
the AND gate(output) will be true only if both inputs are true(1)

true if i==1 && k==1
false if i==0 && k==0,i==1 && k==0,i==0 && k==1.
```